# Data Adapter in Ado.net

Tags: ado.net

An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\vinod\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: dataset is not allowing me to read the Employee Details from the Sql server and it is the above Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the exception message I guess that you are using LocalDb ... so you could just start Microsoft management studio and enter "(localdb)\v11.0" as server name ... then expand the "databases" node and remove everything that sounds like "aspnetdb.mdf" ...